# What is the default cursor icon for delete?

Tags: html, css

In the process of building an app and I was setting it up so when you hold the control key and click on a checkbox it would change to a remove (x) rather than an add (✓).

I am able to add a class to my element when the keydown occurs and remove it when the keyup occurs.  I also have it working on the click, however the problem I'm running into is I want to show a delete/remove cursor.

I know we have default icons for many things including adding something, but I can't seem to find anything for deleting/removing.   Does anyone have a valid method of showing delete, other than building your own icon?  I would like to avoid this, as each browser/os has different icons.   Thus far other than creating my own icon, it seems like no-drop might be my closest choice?

Is there something I'm missing, hopefully someone has a better method of handling this than I do that would work with chrome/IE/FF/safari?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

```
.add-item { cursor: copy; }
.remove-item { cursor: ????; }
```

Comment: The "copy" cursor might well double for adding, but for deleting none of the default cursors are helpful.  You could probably create one like copy, but with a trash an icon next to it.  Or maybe a minus to complement the plus.

Comment: I find it easier to use a .gif as a background url image to the cursor like so: `cursor { url(deletecursor.gif); }` which would be cross browser compatible... however if `not-allowed` serves you well then do use it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There isn't one but you can create your own icon and use `cursor: url();` CSS to accomplish this.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

**Example:**

```css
div {
  cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUGV0.png"), auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover Here</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was doing, but with a different X.   Though it seems this might be my only option.

Comment: @Vince - see updated answer.  This might be more what you are looking for.

Comment: Though not the answer I wanted, seems like this is by best bet. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[Here is a list of cursor properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).

`cursor: not-allowed` seems to be the only one similar to a "deleted" property. [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=not-allowed).

You can also use the `url` property to insert your own custom image.

Answer (score 6):

`not-allowed` is the only one that makes sense, however the custom jpg `url` option looks pretty simple.

You could also rethink your UI design to get around this.  You could just stick with the intuitive default behavior of a checkbox, and let the user click it with the understanding that the checkmark will toggle.  No fancy control key, no fancy cursors.  Maybe just a pointer icon in either case.  With some separate add / remove action buttons.

You could also think about showing some clickable icons for add / remove (per item if applicable).  Thus not using a checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple options to get the expected result.

However it's not the default option, using `cursor: url()` to display a custom image should work fine.

Otherwise use one of the default properties, of which `not-allowed` is probably the best option.
[More about cursor properties](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/)

**Default cursors:**

```html
<p>Mouse over the words to change the cursor.</p>
<span style="cursor:auto">auto</span><br>
<span style="cursor:crosshair">crosshair</span><br>
<span style="cursor:default">default</span><br>
<span style="cursor:e-resize">e-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:grab">grab</span><br>
<span style="cursor:help">help</span><br>
<span style="cursor:move">move</span><br>
<span style="cursor:n-resize">n-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:ne-resize">ne-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:nw-resize">nw-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:pointer">pointer</span><br>
<span style="cursor:progress">progress</span><br>
<span style="cursor:s-resize">s-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:se-resize">se-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:sw-resize">sw-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:text">text</span><br>
<span style="cursor:w-resize">w-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:wait">wait</span><br>
<span style="cursor:not-allowed">not-allowed</span><br>
<span style="cursor:no-drop">no-drop</span><br>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `no-drop` [image: no-drop] or `not-allowed` [image: not-allowed].